# Create single size dynamic UILabel font

Tags: objective-c, string, swift, dynamic, font-size

We all know how to create dynamic UILabel font(Single Line) -

```
 lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
 lbl.numberOfLines = 1
 lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
 lbl.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters
 lbl.textAlignment  = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

The problem is that it gives different results for each given string. So for example if i have a string `"Hello"` and `"Hello World"` the calculated font size will be different.I need to create dynamic font with a single size for all strings.

Example from my project :

[image: MyProject]

Example from iPhone 6 built in camera effects(As you can see all the UILabels font sizes matches) :

[image: Apple]

**What i was thinking to do?**

Basically I know what is the largest string i'll have. So i was thinking somehow calculate(in a effective way) what would be the **font size** for the **largest string** in the given **CGSIze**. So it will always stay in bounds. **Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are the one saying:

```
lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
```

That line *means*, "Hey, iOS, if you feel like shrinking the font, go ahead and shrink it." If you don't want that, then don't say that.

Instead, pick a font size and stick to it. What size? Well, NSString has the ability to tell you the size of a drawn string in a given font/size. So just take your longest string and cycle through different sizes until you find one that fits in the desired space.

Plug your own values into this:

```
    func fontSizeToFit(s:String, fontName:String, intoWidth w:CGFloat) -> CGFloat? {
        let desiredMaxWidth = w
        for i in (8...20).reverse() {
            let d = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:fontName, size:CGFloat(i))!]
            let sz = (s as NSString).sizeWithAttributes(d)
            if sz.width <= desiredMaxWidth {
                return(CGFloat(i))
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    print(fontSizeToFit("Transferation", fontName:"GillSans", intoWidth:50)) // 9.0
```

(There used to be an elegant string drawing feature where you could let the font shrink *and* NSString would tell you how much it shrank to fit; but that feature is broken, alas, so I can't advise you to use it.)

Comment: Hey matt, Thank you for your comment. I know that it's not the right way to use it *IF* you are looking for same font sizes, obviously. I just putted it out there so people won't suggest this method. Basicly what i need to do(In a efficient way). With Frame Size(UILabel frame) and given string(including font name) -> get in return the font-size needed

Comment: And I've answered that. Just do a quick loop through, say, 10 different sizes. Nothing inefficient. It won't take a millisecond. Trust me. I've done this a zillion times.

Comment: Yes. That what i was planning to do, Just wanted to try get a better results. Now-days we have iPhone 4 to iPad retina -> Huge difference. And im using autoLayout to set up my view and it's all relative to the screen frame size. So for bigger screen it might run more than 10 times

Comment: Would it be more smart trying make the algorithm smarter instead of looking for a different way?

Comment: Added actual code. Believe me, this takes no time at all. You are wasting your own time optimizing prematurely.

Comment: matt, How the hell did you figured it's GiliSans?

Comment: Thank you matt, I have gotta say - overthinking sometimes is a pure crime, Again - Thank you! Works like charm!

Comment: There used to be an elegant way to do this, as I said, but it broke. I have a bug report in...

Comment: Yap, For great UI this things is really needed. BTW , this method returns nil , Just to be sure , In whats cases it'll return nil?

Comment: In case we didn't find any answer in the given range (here, 8 thru 20, but you can change that too if you like).

Comment: and Just another things that just came to my mind, Wouldn't it be better to check if the given size(from the attributes string) will be in rage of the max width and 95% of it.So we can be sure it wont be too small?