# How to calculate the font size according to the frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, frame, uifont

Hello i am using [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) to display icons inside uilabel.

so here is an example for such code:

```
        iconTest = UILabel();
        iconTest.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        iconTest.center = self.view.center;

        iconTest.font = UIFont(name: "icomoon", size:80.0);
        iconTest.text = "\u{e904}"
```

if i need to display the icon inside this frame, `CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)` How to calculate the font size which fit the label inside thae frame.

thanks

Comment: Have you checked all the properties of UILabel that are related to the number of lines and the font size ?

Comment: Have you checked all the properties of UIFont that tell you how big things are?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160574/create-single-size-dynamic-uilabel-font As I point out there, it's perfectly reasonable to cycle through font sizes until you find the largest one that fits.